# What is the list of environment variables recognised by ansible?

Tags: ansible

I tried to find a list of environment variables that are recognised by ansible but I wasn't able to find one.

I know what a variable like `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` is recognised but I also found out that `ANSIBLE_TAGS` is not recognised as an alternative to the use of `--tags xxx`.

Is there a list of recognised variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of them can be found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.3.1.0-1/lib/ansible/constants.py). (Ansible pre 2.4)

**UPDATE:**

In Ansible 2.4 there is a [complete revamp](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/74842adc07edb248f9b544389ce4093b9149f195) of configuration process.
There is a new cli `ansible-config` to view/modify configuration.
You can list all available settings with `ansible-config list`.
Or take a look at [this](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/9fc6f8547323c6b5fc1546cd1c1c7e98a4e6eb31/lib/ansible/config/data/config.yml) description file.

Comment: `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` is not in that list .. ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I've updated the answer with tag-fixed url to previous version of `constants.py` and described Ansible 2.4 major changes.

Comment: the list is now at: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.4/lib/ansible/config/base.yml